# VHDL - range direction of variable length generic

Tags: vhdl

I would like to have some variable length generic in my entity however it looks like the default range direction is `to` what collides with internal signals ranges that are declared with `downto`.

```
entity my_entity is
    generic (
        GEN: std_ulogic_vector := b"100_0000_0000_0000_0000_1000" &
                                  b"0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000" &
                                  b"0000_0000_0001"
    );
    port (
        clk: in std_ulogic;
        reset: in std_ulogic;
        a: in std_ulogic_vector(63 downto 0);
        b: out std_ulogic_vector(63 downto 0)
    );
end;
```

Is there any language specific mechanism to inform VHDL tools that range direction of GEN is `downto` not `to`? Right now, the only solution I can think of is to use some extra constant in declarative part of architecture with the same value but different range direction.

Comment: The used "default" direction comes from the declaration of `std_ulogic_vector`. It uses a `positive` index, that in turn is defined from `0 to integer'high`. So you could enforce another "default direction" by creating another integer subtype and a new vector type :). This [ascend](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/common/utils.vhdl?ts=2#L1114) function can be used to enforce an ascending range. See `desend` for the opposite direction.

Answer (score 2):

Because there's almost always more than one way:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity my_entity is
    generic (
        UNBOUND_GEN: std_ulogic_vector := b"100_0000_0000_0000_0000_1000" &
                                  b"0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000" &
                                  b"0000_0000_0001"
    );
    port (
        clk: in std_ulogic;
        reset: in std_ulogic;
        a: in std_ulogic_vector(63 downto 0);
        b: out std_ulogic_vector(63 downto 0)
    );
    alias  GEN: std_ulogic_vector (UNBOUND_GEN'length - 1 downto 0) 
              is UNBOUND_GEN;
end entity;
```

The alias can also be declared as an architecture declarative item or in the immediately enclosing declarative region of where it is used in an architecture.

In a -2008 compliant VHDL tool implementation the alias can be dispensed with and a second generic declaration depending on the first can be used:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity my_entity1 is
    generic (
        UNBOUND_GEN: std_ulogic_vector := b"100_0000_0000_0000_0000_1000" &
                                  b"0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000" &
                                  b"0000_0000_0001";
        GEN: std_ulogic_vector (UNBOUND_GEN'length - 1 downto 0) := UNBOUND_GEN

    );
    port (
        clk: in std_ulogic;
        reset: in std_ulogic;
        a: in std_ulogic_vector(63 downto 0);
        b: out std_ulogic_vector(63 downto 0)
    );
    -- alias  GEN: std_ulogic_vector (UNBOUND_GEN'length - 1 downto 0)
    --           is UNBOUND_GEN;
end entity;
```

Comment: I haven't ever seen an alias used in the entity declaration like that. Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is not a way to inform the tools of a direction without also specifying the range.

Typically if I needed a variable length generic I would use a second generic to define its length. Using your example it would look like this:

```
entity my_entity is
    generic (
        GEN_LEN: positive := 59; -- positive forces len >= 1
        GEN: std_ulogic_vector(GEN_LEN-1 downto 0) := 
                                  b"100_0000_0000_0000_0000_1000" &
                                  b"0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000" &
                                  b"0000_0000_0001"
    );
    port (
        clk: in std_ulogic;
        reset: in std_ulogic;
        a: in std_ulogic_vector(63 downto 0);
        b: out std_ulogic_vector(63 downto 0)
    );
end;
```

I understand that this is probably not nearly as pretty as what you were hoping for. It does handle your use case though.